# How to rewrite a user from a non rewritten url to a rewritten url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have two URLs. One looks like this way (which is a non rewritten URL):

1. `www.example.com/article.php?id=12`

And the next one is looks like this (which is a rewritten URL):

2. `www.example.com/article/12`

Both the URLs are working. What I want to know is if a user visits the first URL can he be redirected to the second URL automatically? How can I achieve this? Is there a way to do the same only using `.htaccess` file?

Also please help if i wanted to include title also with this my ugly url will looks like this.

`www.example.com/article.php?id=12&title=sometitle`

And the expected pretty url is like this

`www.example.com/article/12/sometitle`

The redirection rule which i am using looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2[R=302,L]
```

I don want users to see the ugly url even if he visits the ugly one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With redirects like this you need to be extra careful of redirect loops, since you are already *internally rewriting* the other way round (from `/article/12` to `/article.php?id=12`). To avoid the redirect loop, you can check the URL against `THE_REQUEST` server variable, which holds the initial request header, and does not change when the URL is rewritten.

So, you can do something like the following, near the top of your `.htaccess` file, before the *internal rewrites*.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([\w-]+)\.php\?id=(\d+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+\.php$ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]
```

(Change the `302` (temporary) to a `301` (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached by the browser so can make testing problematic. Alternatively, ensure you test with browser caching disabled.)

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is required in order to remove the original query from the request. (Alternatively, you can use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+)

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* is just a quick check to ensure we only process URLs that look like the ones we want to target. The backreferences `%1` and `%2` refer back to the *CondPattern*.

The pattern `[\w-]+` matches article "names" that contain the *word* characters `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, `_` and `-`. If the article names are only lowercase `a`-`z` then change this pattern to `[a-z]+`. It is better to be more restrictive with the regex.

Likewise `\d+` matches any number of digits (`0`-`9`).

**UPDATE#1:** It would seem (from comments) that "article" is the literal word, rather than a word representing *any* article. In which case, the above directives can be simplified:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(article)\.php\?id=(\d+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]
```

**UPDATE#2:** To incorporate a "title", you can just extend the above example (although I'm not sure why you would need to do this). So, to redirect from `/article.php?id=12&title=some-title` to `/article/12/some-title`, you can do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(article)\.php\?id=(\d+)&title=([\w-]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: If the urls are having special characters on url then it is not getting redirected i have tried with this in at the title part title=([\w-][\ |%2520]+) but it is seems like not working.

Comment: I have posted it as a new question over here http://serverfault.com/questions/823353/how-to-redirect-a-url-which-has-space-on-in-it