# How to redirect a url which has space on in it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting from this URL

```
www.example.com/article.php?id=12&title=some-title
```

to this URL

```
www.example.com/article/12/some-title
```

Using these URL rewriting rules

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(article)\.php\?id=(\d+)&title=([\w-]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2[R=301,L]
```

But if the URL has a *space* in it for example

```
www.example.com/article.php?id=12&title=some%20title
```

Then the above rule will not work. How can I make this URL work with the rule mentioned above only using `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2[R=301,L]
> ```

Bit of a side issue, but you are missing a *space* before the `RewriteRule` flags which will result in an erroneous rewrite. It should be: `...&title=$2 [R=301,L]`.

With regards to the space character (`%20` when URL/percent encoded)... the `THE_REQUEST` contains the URL encoded character, but the URL-path matched against the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is URL decoded (ie. a literal space). In the above example, this means two different regex patterns. So, in order to match a *space* in the `title` you can modify your existing rules something like:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(article)\.php\?id=(\d+)&title=([\w%-]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /%1/%2/%3? [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/([\w\s-]+)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Each directive is modified slightly.

- The *CondPattern* now allows for a literal percent character (ie. `[\w%-]`).
- The `NE` flag is required on the following `RewriteRule` to prevent the URL encoded space from being double encoded (eg. `%2520`).
- And the last `RewriteRule` requires `\s` (any whitespace character) being added to the *pattern*. (Alternatively, you could just use a backslash escaped space, ie. `\`, or just a *space* and surround the entire *pattern* in double quotes.)

This just permits the additional *space*. Although the *CondPattern* now allows *any* percent encoded character, the `RewriteRule` pattern restricts this to *whitespace*.

---

**UPDATE#1:** To allow *some* additional characters... `[\w%-]` (everything between the square brackets) is a regex *character class*. To allow more characters you just add these characters to the character class. eg. In the case of `,`, `'` and `;`, this becomes `[\w%,';-]`. Note that the hyphen (`-`) must appear at the start or end of the character class, since it is a special meta character.

To allow *any* characters then you can change the pattern to `.+`. Which is simply 1 or more characters. The dot indicates *any* character. So, this would become:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(article)\.php\?id=(\d+)&title=(.+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /%1/%2/%3? [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/(.+) article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am getting a 404 error from this

Comment: You might have had a caching issue - make sure browser cache is cleared before testing.

Comment: Yes, It was a caching issue

Comment: Also it is not redirecting %25 only %20

Comment: Is there a way to replace the space with this -

Comment: As mentioned above, this only allows a _space_. I can modify it for _any_ character. But allowing _any_ character does pose more of a security risk so you must ensure this data is being strictly validated. Also, `%25` is an encoded `%` - this shouldn't really be in the URL?

Comment: How to allow any character with this rule?

Comment: Also how to allow for some selected characters  such as ,' ; like this

Comment: Note that these are standard regular expressions (regex), not specific to Apache. I've updated my answer.